# Add Div Dynamically using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm not sure if this would be the best option.. But I want the option that when the user clicks a button, it will add another div or li.

I am going to allow users to upload documents, but multiple ones. I'd like to for the user to be able to click a button, and a new `<div>` or `<li>` is generated with predefined code. Is this possible?

Here's a fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/AHvwP/1/

Comment: Yes, it is possible to create new DOM elements with JavaScript. Have you tried anything? There are plenty of jQuery tutorials out there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Your example updated on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AHvwP/2/)

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
    $("<li />").html("item").appendTo("ul");
})
```

You can create elements using `$("<tag />")` and set attributes, add classes and so on. Then append where you want.

Comment: is there a way to make this animated?

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('#myContainer').append('<div>the new guy</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add a new element to an existing parent like so:

select the element to added the new `<div>/<li>` to and use `.append()`

```
$("#id").append("<div>foo</div>");
```

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Alternatively, you can use the `.html()`

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 1):

If this is to allow for multiple file uploads, have you considered using something like http://www.uploadify.com/ the jQuery plugin? It allows multiple file uploads from one dialog window and you wouldn't need to worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
    $("<li />").html("item").appendTo("ul");
})
```

You can create elements using `$("<tag />")` and set attributes, add classes and so on. Then append where you want.