# Dynamically adding contents of an input to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field and a div. I want to put a live preview in a div. This is the code I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/6Wp2j/1/

```
$('#source').on('keyup', function() {

});
```

I know that I need to look out for a keyup but I don't know how to move the contents to the div. Can anyone tell me how to do this please?

Comment: look at this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852686/add-div-dynamically-using-jquery

Comment: Be careful about jsfiddle options : "no-wrap in head" makes the code unable to find the dom elements initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Wp2j/21/)

You just need to add `$(".preview").html(this.value);` inside your code.

Comment: @NicoSantangelo $(".preview").html(this.value);

Comment: @Naveen that's what I ment, and that's what Jacob updated in the answer. Much cleaner :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like should work:

```
$("#source").on("keyup", function(){
    $("#mydiv").html($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
$('#source').on('keyup', function() {
  var data = $(this).val();
  $('#result').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#source').on('keyup', function() {
    $(".preview").html(this.value);
});
```